# Python Multiprocessing Running Itself Instead of Imported Script

Tags: python, multiprocessing

New to trying multiprocessing with Python, however what I'm experiencing doesn't make any sense based on what I've read on this site and elsewhere. Here is the code I have:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import some_func

cpu_count = mp.cpu_count()
print(cpu_count)

## Some code to build list of function arguments in list 'tasks'

pool = mp.Pool(cpu_count)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    for x in tasks:
        pool.apply_async(some_func.func, x)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

The first line of some_func.func is:
`print('running import',first_variable)`
so I should see obviously each time the function is began.

Instead, I am seeing the cpu_count variable printed out continuously, and some_func.func never being called.

Comment: `apply_async` has a return value.Check weather `apply_async` succeed.And what's the type of `x`?

Comment: If you don't want to see many `cpu_count ` printed,move `print(cpu_count)` inside the `if`.Otherwise it will be executed in every subprocess.

Comment: You need to put the creation of the pool inside the `main`.  You only want it running on one thread, not all of them.